# Tetromino translation without tilting my head

Tags: fez

What are the tetrominoes translated without tilting my head ? I'm asking this because I don't understand what it means by *tilt your head 90⁰ right*.

Comment: You need to clarify a bit your question. I understand what you're trying to ask but you need to put a bit more effort into it.

Answer (score 2):

> Use the cypher when reading rune sequences from TOP to BOTTOM. You
>   must stand under the tablet with runes, or under a set of runes on a
>   wall, and tap the button combinations on the controller with less than
>   a second of time in between for the code to work. You will get the
>   Cryptographer Achievement the first time you input a code correctly.

[image]

[Source and other examples are located here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/fez/Code_Solutions)

Comment: uhh... you don't have to do it with _1_ second, 5 works too.